# How to scanning lines, each line differently, in c?

Tags: c, file, malloc, scanf

Lets say i have this text file for example:

`4
1 2 3 4
3 9 8 7
1 1 2 1
8 7 8 6`

I want to store the first line ("`4`") to one variable, and the other lines, 
insert them to 2d matrix as the way they showing (dynamic 2d array).

Notice that its just example, i just know that the first line is one char, and i don't know the len of the rest of the lines except that are N*N matrix.

How can i do this in C?

**Edited:** so the matrix should only have numbers, so sor example this txt file:
`4
1 2 3 4
3 9 8 7
1 W 2 1
8 7 8 6` is illegal . how can i handle this?

Comment: The first value you get from the file is the size of matrix, isnt it? And what you have done so far?

Comment: correct. i just know that fscanf scan each line, but wants to know "how much parameter exactly" to insert value to them.
so i have first line ok i know its just 1, but in the other lines, i don't know realy how many "numbers" will be

Comment: first line is the number of lines you will have in each line then. if the first value you get is 4 you will need to declare 4x4 2d array and put the matrix values inside that 2d array.

Comment: how many "numbers"? : 4*4(first number * first number)

Comment: @user1722022 the implementation of this..., what you wrote its exactly  the question

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yest but its just an example. there is any function in c that run on chars-in-lines?

Comment: _how can i handle this?_ check return value of `fscanf`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY right, if fscanf(..)==1 , correct?

Comment: 1 : this was read one element. 0 : this can't read element. EOF(-1):  EOF. That failed to read if it is not 1 in the case of one `"%d"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    int n;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);
    int (*mat)[n] = malloc(sizeof(int[n][n]));
    int *p = &mat[0][0];

    while(p < &mat[n-1][n])
        fscanf(fp, "%d", p++);
    fclose(fp);
    //check
    for(int r=0; r < n; ++r){
        for(int c=0; c < n; ++c)
            printf("%d ", mat[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'while(p < &mat[n-1][n])
fscanf(fp, "%d", p++);'

this is making the entire matrix as i asked? i don't understand why

Comment: you can change to `int numOfTotal = n*n; while(numOfTotal--)fscanf(fp, "%d", p++);`

Comment: but when fscanf know to go to the next line? or even go to the next char in the same line?

Comment: @user2637293 `%d` of `fscanf` skip blank characer (`' '`(space), `'\n'`(newline), `'\t'`(tab)).